# How to get time from time dimension with a specific relationship?

Tags: powerbi, dax

My data

Fact

```
iddimUser iddimtime
123       81200
124       84500
```

DimTime

```
iddimtime FullTime
81200     08:12:00.0000000
84500     08:45:00.0000000
```

Desired Table calculation

```
iddimUser iddimtime Time
123       81200     08:12:00.0000000
124       84500     08:45:00.0000000
```

I require to bring to the fact table a specific time from the time dimension base on one of the multiple relationships I have (I have several IdTimes in the fact table).
I tried this column calculation but getting an "A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected" error

```
FullTime = TIME(
    HOUR(CALCULATE( VALUES(DimTime[FullTime] ),
                   USERELATIONSHIP ( Fact[iddimtime], DimTime[iddimtime]))),
    MINUTE(CALCULATE( VALUES(DimTime[FullTime] ),
                    USERELATIONSHIP ( Fact[iddimtime], DimTime[iddimtime]))),
    SECOND(CALCULATE( VALUES(DimTime[FullTime] ),
                    USERELATIONSHIP ( Fact[IniciaProce], DimTime[iddimtime]))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use the userelationship if there is only one active relationship between fact and dim tables ? All you need is the related function to access the related row in the dim table:

Note:

- Ensure that The [iddimtime] column is the one who creates the relationship between both tables.
- Related() is an iterator. Never use it with a calculate involving USERELATIONSHIP() in a calculated field.
- RELATED() is used to access the column values from many side to one-side. Conversely, RELATEDTABLE() is used to access columns from one side to many side.

Please test this, and let me know if It solves your problem.

```
FullTime =
TIME ( HOUR ( RELATED ( DimTime[FullTime] ) ), MINUTE ( RELATED ( DimTime[FullTime] ) ), SECOND ( RELATED ( DimTime[FullTime] ) ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FullTime1 = 
FORMAT(RELATED(DimTime[FullTime]),"hh:nn:ss")
```

---

This you can use as alternative to your measure and it will be much faster.

```
FullTime2 =
    FORMAT(
        LOOKUPVALUE(
            DimTime[FullTime]
            ,DimTime[iddimtime]
            ,[iddimtime]
        )
        ,"hh:nn:ss"
    )
```